# Criteria: "undefined offset"

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel, offset

i have this schema below, i have generated the classes using symfony
and created a pair of objects using the form class generated.

```
moto:
  marca: { type: varchar(255), required: true }
  matricula: { type: integer, required: true }
```

Now i have this criteria:

```
  $c = new Criteria();
  $c->addSelectColumn('MAX('.MotoPeer::MATRICULA.')');
  $max_matricula = MotoPeer::doSelect($c);
  var_dump($max_matricula);
  return $max_matricula;
```

When i call the criteria code It works ok, but these three notices
below are showed.

Any idea?

sf 1.4/propel 1.4

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/lib/
>   model/om/BaseMotoPeer.php on line 379
>   Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function        Location 1       0.0008  328076
>
> {main}( )       ../frontend_dev.php:0
>   2       0.1974  4333236
>   sfContext->dispatch( )
>   ../frontend_dev.php:13 3       0.1974 
>   4333264
>   sfFrontWebController->dispatch( )
>   ../ sfContext.class.php:170 4
>   0.1981  4350256 sfController->forward( )     ../
>   sfFrontWebController.class.php:48 5
>   0.2134  4641000 sfFilterChain->execute( )
>   ../sfController.class.php: 238 6
>   0.2138  4641808 sfRenderingFilter->execute( )
>   ../ sfFilterChain.class.php:53 7
>   0.2138  4641808 sfFilterChain->execute( )    ../
>   sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33 8
>   0.2143  4642588 sfExecutionFilter->execute( )
>   ../ sfFilterChain.class.php:53 9
>   0.2144  4643308 sfExecutionFilter->handleAction( )
>   ../ sfExecutionFilter.class.php:42 10 
>   0.2144  4643308 sfExecutionFilter->executeAction( ) 
>   ../ sfExecutionFilter.class.php:78 11 
>   0.2144  4643336 sfActions->execute( )        ../sfExecutionFilter.class.php: 92 12 
>   0.2147  4644160 motoActions->executePrueba( )
>   ../sfActions.class.php: 60 13
>   0.2212  5026172 MotoPeer::prueba( )     ../actions.class.php:14 14      0.2254
>   5285592 BaseMotoPeer::doSelect( )
>   ../MotoPeer.php:26 15      0.2493 
>   5756176 BaseMotoPeer::populateObjects(
>   )        ../BaseMotoPeer.php: 241 16
>   0.2493  5756568 BaseMotoPeer::getPrimaryKeyHashFromRow(
>   )       ../ BaseMotoPeer.php:400
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/lib/
>   model/om/BaseMoto.php on line 184 Call
>   Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function        Location 1       0.0008  328076
>
> {main}( )       ../frontend_dev.php:0
>   2       0.1974  4333236
>   sfContext->dispatch( )
>   ../frontend_dev.php:13 3       0.1974 
>   4333264
>   sfFrontWebController->dispatch( )
>   ../ sfContext.class.php:170 4
>   0.1981  4350256 sfController->forward( )     ../
>   sfFrontWebController.class.php:48 5
>   0.2134  4641000 sfFilterChain->execute( )
>   ../sfController.class.php: 238 6
>   0.2138  4641808 sfRenderingFilter->execute( )
>   ../ sfFilterChain.class.php:53 7
>   0.2138  4641808 sfFilterChain->execute( )    ../
>   sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33 8
>   0.2143  4642588 sfExecutionFilter->execute( )
>   ../ sfFilterChain.class.php:53 9
>   0.2144  4643308 sfExecutionFilter->handleAction( )
>   ../ sfExecutionFilter.class.php:42 10 
>   0.2144  4643308 sfExecutionFilter->executeAction( ) 
>   ../ sfExecutionFilter.class.php:78 11 
>   0.2144  4643336 sfActions->execute( )        ../sfExecutionFilter.class.php: 92 12 
>   0.2147  4644160 motoActions->executePrueba( )
>   ../sfActions.class.php: 60 13
>   0.2212  5026172 MotoPeer::prueba( )     ../actions.class.php:14 14      0.2254
>   5285592 BaseMotoPeer::doSelect( )
>   ../MotoPeer.php:26 15      0.2493 
>   5756176 BaseMotoPeer::populateObjects(
>   )        ../BaseMotoPeer.php: 241 16
>   0.2578  5953424 BaseMoto->hydrate( ) ../BaseMotoPeer.php:408
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/prueba/lib/
>   model/om/BaseMoto.php on line 185 Call
>   Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function        Location 1       0.0008  328076
>
> {main}( )       ../frontend_dev.php:0
>   2       0.1974  4333236
>   sfContext->dispatch( )
>   ../frontend_dev.php:13 3       0.1974 
>   4333264
>   sfFrontWebController->dispatch( )
>   ../ sfContext.class.php:170 4
>   0.1981  4350256 sfController->forward( )     ../
>   sfFrontWebController.class.php:48 5
>   0.2134  4641000 sfFilterChain->execute( )
>   ../sfController.class.php: 238 6
>   0.2138  4641808 sfRenderingFilter->execute( )
>   ../ sfFilterChain.class.php:53 7
>   0.2138  4641808 sfFilterChain->execute( )    ../
>   sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33 8
>   0.2143  4642588 sfExecutionFilter->execute( )
>   ../ sfFilterChain.class.php:53 9
>   0.2144  4643308 sfExecutionFilter->handleAction( )
>   ../ sfExecutionFilter.class.php:42 10 
>   0.2144  4643308 sfExecutionFilter->executeAction( ) 
>   ../ sfExecutionFilter.class.php:78 11 
>   0.2144  4643336 sfActions->execute( )        ../sfExecutionFilter.class.php: 92 12 
>   0.2147  4644160 motoActions->executePrueba( )
>   ../sfActions.class.php: 60 13
>   0.2212  5026172 MotoPeer::prueba( )     ../actions.class.php:14 14      0.2254
>   5285592 BaseMotoPeer::doSelect( )
>   ../MotoPeer.php:26 15      0.2493 
>   5756176 BaseMotoPeer::populateObjects(
>   )        ../BaseMotoPeer.php: 241 16
>   0.2578  5953424 BaseMoto->hydrate( ) ../BaseMotoPeer.php:408

EDIT: the **first notice** appears because i didn't write "id: ~" before the fields of the model. Here it goes the lines that causes **the second and the third notices**:

```
    /**
     * Hydrates (populates) the object variables with values from the database resultset.
     *
     * An offset (0-based "start column") is specified so that objects can be hydrated
     * with a subset of the columns in the resultset rows.  This is needed, for example,
     * for results of JOIN queries where the resultset row includes columns from two or
     * more tables.
     *
     * @param      array $row The row returned by PDOStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
     * @param      int $startcol 0-based offset column which indicates which restultset column to start with.
     * @param      boolean $rehydrate Whether this object is being re-hydrated from the database.
     * @return     int next starting column
     * @throws     PropelException  - Any caught Exception will be rewrapped as a PropelException.
     */
    public function hydrate($row, $startcol = 0, $rehydrate = false)
    {
        try {

var_dump($row);

    $this->id = ($row[$startcol + 0] !== null) ? (int) $row[$startcol + 0] : null; 
    $this->marca = ($row[$startcol + 1] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 1] : null;//184
    $this->matricula = ($row[$startcol + 2] !== null) ? (int) $row[$startcol + 2] : null;//185
```

I think, the second and the third notices are showed because in the criteria I'm just getting one column (maatricula). But how to do it so?

Javier

Comment: posting the lines referred to in the notices would help...

Comment: hi, thanks, i posted more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "AddSelectColumn" method:

```
$c->addSelectColumn('MAX('.MotoPeer::MATRICULA.')');
```

you cannot hydrate the object - you are not selecting all the columns. Hence do not call:

```
MotoPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Instead do this:

```
$c->addSelectColumn('MAX('.MotoPeer::MATRICULA.')');
$stmt = MotoPeer::doSelectStmt($c);
$max_matricula = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
```

Here you execute the SQL statement and fetch the single value that you're interested in into the variable $max_matricula.